# How to pass command line parameters with space in Batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file

I need to pass parameter line `AB CD` to a batch file from the command line. This parameter refer to a file name.

If I use use `AB CD` the script just pick the first part and return `Unable to find the file AB.txt`

If I put quote around my parameters like `"AB CD"` the I got

```
"AB CD".txt 
Illegal characters in path.
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

you can use %~1 instead of %1

e.g a test.bat with :

```
echo %~1
```

then a call to `test "abc de"` will display :

```
abc de
```

Comment: that what I found from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473117/pass-path-with-spaces-as-parameter-to-bat-file

Answer (score 13):

what you can do is

```
>batch.bat "ab cd.txt"
```

When the parameters contain whitespace, you can enclose them in quotes.

Comment: two things, I can not add the extension in my parameters as it is use somewhere in my batch script else without the file extension. Second when I add quote, there are added in the file name (see last example of my questions)

Comment: Well, in that case, I guess the issue is not with passing parameters, it is with the programming in batch file. You can check this by creating a simple batch file with this simple line echo %1, this will echo the full name "ab cd". It means that you are passing the parameters correctly but there is somewhere in the batch file it is not treated properly. Somewhere, it is trying to recreate the file name with breaking it apart and adding extension.

Comment: agree. I actually need to use %~1 instead of %1 in my script

Comment: You should either use %~p1 for path or %~n1 for file name, not just %~1

Comment: or a combination of these

Answer (score 2):

if it only accept 1 paramenter use `"%*"` you don't need to quote the parameter

`myapp.cmd`

```
@echo off
echo "%*"
```

test it

```
myapp single parameter with space
```

Comment: The selected answer doesn't work for me, but this worked... After two hours of Googling.