# How to pass CMD argument with spaces?

Tags: c#, cmd, arguments

I want to run simple `CMD` command and my `argument` contains spaces (" ").

In this case this is not working since its recognized as command with several `arguments`...

This is what I have tried (same results):

```
string arg = "c:\my path\ this is test\file.doc";

string.Format("\"{0}\"", arg)
```

Edit:

```
public void Invoke(string fileName, string arg)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    processStartInfo.FileName = fileName;
    if (arg != "")
        processStartInfo.Arguments = arg;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
    process.Exited += Process_Exited;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
}
```

Usage:

```
string arg = "c:\my path\this is my string.ps1";   
Invoke(@"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe", string.Format("\"{0}\"", arg));
```

Comment: "not working since this recognized as command with several arguments"  where is your code that is supposedly doing this?  I don't see where you're using it....is this a console application:?  Please show **all relevant code**

Comment: Quoting it is the correct way. How are you reading the arguments? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639663/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-with-space-in-batch-file). Also fyi `string arg = "c:\ this is test\file.doc";` does not compile, you want `string arg = @"c:\ this is test\file.doc";` or `string arg = "c:\\ this is test\\file.doc";`

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: The title here is incorrect and misleading. What you're using is *not* the classic Windows Command Line tool *UNIVERSALLY* known as *CMD*. Please edit your title to *PowerShell* so that people don't waste their time here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
string arg = @"c:\\"my path\"\\"this is my string.ps1\"";   
Invoke(@"C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe", 
string.Format("\"{0}\"", arg));
```

or 
    string arg = @"c:/\"my path\"/\"this is my string.ps1\"";

Answer (score 0):

Within your application join all the arguments together to get a single space separated argument like this:

```
var joinedArgs = string.Join(" ", args);
```

Then pass the joined args to your function.