# How can I pass a JSON string to a Python program's command line on Windows?

Tags: python, json, windows, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I have a script that is called from another process that receives an input that is a json string.

```
import sys
import json

script_name, json_in = sys.argv
```

my json in looks something like:

```
'{"key1":"val1", "key2":[val2, val3], "key3":"val4"}'
```

when i print what is received by python and stored in `json_in` it looks like:

```
{key1:val1, key2:[val2, val3], key:val4}
```

stepping through the pdb when i get to `json_in` it's value is:

```
"'{key:val1, key2:[val2, vale3], key:val4}'"
```

i wasn't having this problem on Ubuntu, but when i use the same script on Windows it no longer works.

The script does work if you copy and paste the exact same input that is being passed to argv. So the only conclusion i've been able to come to is that argv is somehow stripping the double quotes? I haven't found any documentation that might describe why this is happening (especially when it works on Ubuntu).

Does anyone know why its being stripped?

The python function is being called by javascript function, but even if i just call the python scipt from the terminal using

```
>>> python file_name.py '{"key1":"val1", "key2":[val2, val3], "key3":"val4"}'
```

I get the same error. If you set the `json_in` variable to the same value, or call it in the exact same way in the Ubuntu terminal, then there is no problem.

Comment: How are you printing? Are you using `repr()`?

Comment: @SunnyPatel Do you mean between processes? I'm actually calling the python script from a javascript file using `exec()`. The same process works on Ubuntu, so maybe its a pipelining issue?

Comment: If you mean printing in general i've tried writing to a file or command prompt with print, and sys.write.

Comment: Show how your program is invoked from the operating system.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, i've updated the question to further reflect the problem

Comment: The Windows shell (`cmd.exe`) doesn't honor single quotes, so that not working is entirely unsurprising.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy okay that makes a lot of sense. Do you have a suggestion for it then?

Comment: Assuming that the accepted answer to [How to escape command line arguments for the `cmd.exe` shell on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213106/how-to-securely-escape-command-line-arguments-for-the-cmd-exe-shell-on-windows) is correct, this would look like `^"{\^"key1\^":\^"val1\^", \^"key2\^":[val2, val3], \^"key3\^":\^"val4\^"}^"`. If that works, let me know and I'll flag this question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: (...mind you, `cmd.exe` doesn't actually *do* parsing on Windows -- programs are responsible for parsing their own arguments there rather than having it done by the caller; for typical programs with a `int main(int argc, char** argv)` entry point this is done by the standard C library, but it's not a firm guarantee that any two Windows programs will parse an argument the same way. One more respect in which that whole platform is a %$@#$ mess).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so excaping it with the `^` did not work at all, but using `\\` worked great, so feel free to flag it

Comment: Easiest way is almost certainly to use PowerShell. Single quoted strings work in it.

Comment: @jpmc26 that was actually my problem. The PC i wrote this on was ubuntu, then i tested it on a windows machine with the linux subsystem. So i couldnt reproduce the issue.

Comment: I found putting single quote arguments with double quotes in front of `"`, `{` and `}` worked. e.g. `python program.py '"{ ""key"": ""value"", ""other"": 10 "}'`. No idea why and annoyingly clunky