# How do I run a command instead of "opens with" when a filetype is executed?

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, windows-10, executable

I have my file type `.unitypackage` e.g. `something.unitypackage`.

And I want to run the command `"E:\Unity\2018.2.1f1\Editor\Unity.exe" -openfile "%1"` whenever the `something.unitypackage` is executed (by Enter or double-click).

How do I achieve this?

It seems like "Opens with" doesn't allow specifying options for my command, so if I just choose Unity.exe to open with, it won't do `-openfile "%1"` option.

Comment: The answer could be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/361816/pass-command-line-arguments-to-windows-open-with).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a batch script `unity.bat` as following :

```
set params=%1
if "%params%" NEQ "" (E:\Unity\2018.2.1f1\Editor\Unity.exe -openfile %params%) else (E:\Unity\2018.2.1f1\Editor\Unity.exe)
```

Than you can 'open with' the `.bat` file.

Comment: It didn't work. The file is executed and nothing happens. Assume the file name is`"D:\off99555\Documents\Unity Projects\[All Assets]\[Scripting]\Best HTTP.unitypackage"` Does this takes into account the space and brackets characters?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473117/pass-path-with-spaces-as-parameter-to-bat-file
Try to change "%params%" to %params%